# Regex for dividing mathematical function

Tags: java, regex, math, calculator

I am programming a derivative calculator and I need to divide a given String output into an array of Strings, but my current splitting command doesn't work that well with negative and i need it to NOT split the minus sign after a *,/,^,(,sin(,cos(,tan( (I still didn't implement sin, cos and tan to my code, but I will so I want to know how to not split the minus sign after it).

Code:

```
public class Graph {
    private String function;
    private final String ONLY_POSITIVE_DELIMITER = "(?<=[+-/*^()])|(?=[+-/*^()])";
    public Graph(String function) {
        this.function = function;
    }

    public String getDerivative() {
        return null;
    }
    private List<String> getArguments() {
        String[] split = function.split(ONLY_POSITIVE_DELIMITER);

        List<String> args = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(split));
        System.out.println("Splitten der Funktion: "+args);
        return args;

    } 
 }
```

This will turn 1 - ( -2 * -1 ) -3 into `[1, -, (, -, 2, *, -, 1, ), -, 3]`, but I want it to turn into: `[1, -, (, -2, *, -1, ), -, 3]`

Comment: No, that is a very bad idea, because nobody would type a mathematical expression like that.

Comment: I did it, because I thought you were referring to the fact that the expression is not clear enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your existing pattern, you might take out the `-` of the first character class, and add an extra alternative to assert a `-` on the left which is not directly followed by one of `*,/,^,(,sin(,cos(,tan(`

```
(?<=[+/*^()])|(?=[+/*^()-])|(?<=-(?<!(?:[*/^(]|(?:sin|cos|tan)\()-))
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9eGeqH/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/ajLzNT)

```
String ONLY_POSITIVE_DELIMITER = "(?<=[+/*^()])|(?=[+/*^()-])|(?<=-(?<!(?:[*/^(]|(?:sin|cos|tan)\\()-))";
String function = "1-(-2*-1)-3";
String[] split = function.split(ONLY_POSITIVE_DELIMITER);

List<String> args = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(split));
System.out.println("Splitten der Funktion: "+args);
```

Output

```
Splitten der Funktion: [1, -, (, -2, *, -1, ), -, 3]
```